# Installing C/C++ Compilers in Android

Tags: android, compiler-construction, android-ndk

Is there any way to have `C/C++ compilers` directly into the Android device ?

Something like I can adb shell the device and run `gcc` or `agcc` or something related to compiling `C\C++` src files.

I googled, but there were just speculations, please help in this !

Thanks in Advance :) :) 
Shoaib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install c4droid you can make an onboard executable by finding the gcc binary and calling it. I also have root on my phone.
On your phone or tablet:
Install c4droid(paid app) and additionally GCC plugin(free).
Install a terminal client. I use Better Term but there are free options as well.

find / -name *gcc*
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/gcc/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

cat > test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){ 
  printf("hello arm!\n");
return 0;
}
```

./mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/gcc/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc test.c -o test

./test

hello arm!

Answer (score 2):

Try C4droid
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc
or this app
https://market.android.com/details?id=GDE.Main